# Dark matter, MOND or flattened gravitational fields?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, dark-matter, modified-gravity

Could there not be a third variant to explain why e.g. long-distance multistar systems rotate faster than Newton's law of gravity suggests?

In addition to the Dark matter hypothesis and MOND then, that the gravitational field, which normally has a spherical character, under certain conditions can tend to a flat circular disc character? As if the field itself are deformed towards the plane of the masses, say of two gravitationally bound stars, and strengthened the field in this plane so that a $1/r²$ proportionality then tended to become a $1/r$ proportionality for gravity, according to measurements?

[image]

The picture illustrate how the gravitational field concentrates in the plane of the movments (comppare with Schwarzschild-linsing?), a deformation seeming more flat the grater the distance between the stars.

Changing Newton's *definition of force* as in MOND does not seem to be the most reasonable thing, although the basic idea that heavy mass is not more than approximately equivalent to inertial mass is worth considering.

---

ChatGPT:
*When multiple stars move around a common center of mass, as in a binary star system or a galaxy, deformed gravitational fields, which depend on how gravity propagates at the speed of light, can lead to the field becoming concentrated or deformed in the plane of motion of the stars.*

*This is a result of gravitational waves (gravity propagating at the speed of light) taking time to travel from one star to another as the stars move. During this time, the stars may have shifted positions, potentially giving rise to a concentration of gravity in the plane of motion.*

> Can this concentration of gravity add some part of the explanation to why long distance stars orbital as gravitating proportionsl to $1/r$?

---

Autor of 'Breakdown of the Newton–Einstein Standard Gravity at Low Acceleration in Internal Dynamics of Wide Binary Stars' in The Astrophysical Journal:

*The retarded time (as a result of gravity propagating at the speed of light) has a negligible impact on the orbital dynamics. This is because during the retarded time (typically months for wide binaries) the stars moved only a very very little fraction of the orbit as the orbital period is much much longer than the retarded time.*

*Also, I did not get 1/r behavior but only a 40% boost of standard gravity 1/r^2. Thus, my result agrees with MOND only when taking into account the external field effect from the Milky Way galaxy. This, of course, increases my confidence in my result.*

*Kind regards,
Kyu-Hyun Chae*

Comment: AFAIK MOND still has some mass defect for structures larger than galaxies, so "MOND or dark matter" may be a framing mistake. I'd be interested in knowing if any astronomers out here can weigh in on that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to state that dark matter has overwhelming observational evidence—as an indirect effect. You are right that there are other explanations for the 'missing matter' we observe. Besides MOND and various (relativistic) generalisations of it (e.g. Tensor-Vector-Scalar ([TeVeS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor%E2%80%93vector%E2%80%93scalar_gravity)) or Gauge Vector-Tensor ([GVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_vector%E2%80%93tensor_gravity)) gravities). There are other approaches that introduce new fields and interactions, such as Scalar-Tensor-Vector ([SVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar%E2%80%93tensor%E2%80%93vector_gravity)) gravity, or approaches that try to generalise GR, e.g. (beyond) [Horndeski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horndeski%27s_theory) theories, where you allow for torsion and/or non-metriticity, besides curvature.

There is a full Wikipedia page on [Alternatives to GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity).

Fun fuct about beyond Horndeski: Horndeski himself is contributing to beyond Horndeski theories.